# Primefaces LazyDataModel sortField - type safety possible?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I was wondering if it's possible, on some way, to make the sortField of the lazyDataModel type safe (something analog to the MetaModel of the criteriaBuilder..).

The LazyDataModel's method has the following method signature:

```
@Override
public List<Visit> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
   ...
}
```

The sortField is a String.. And imagine the following case:

```
class Book { private Cover cover; }
class Cover { private String pictureName; }
```

I'd then like to type something like:

```
@Override
public List<Visit> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
   switch (sortField) {
     case CoverPF_.pictureName:
        // sort on pictureName
   }
}
```

instead of (which is prone to errors..):

```
@Override
public List<Visit> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
   switch (sortField) {
     case "cover.pictureName":
        // sort on pictureName
   }
}
```

Primefaces 5.2

Comment: No obvious way. You can use the `field` attribute with `<p:column>` to possibly give a different, static/constant, meaningful column name so that it does not affect the business logic, when the field name is changed in the corresponding entity class and/or database table.

Comment: @Tiny it's a valid workaround indeed.. I'm keeping this post open though. Who knows someone knows about some plugin that gives me some other possibilities